# How to use callbacks to run 2 function synchronously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function, `foo()`, which I would like to call twice, synchronously.

Each time `foo()` is finished, its callback function should update my `<div>` with a "loaded" message.

HTML:

```
 <div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
 foo('Loaded... 50%', function(str){
      $('div').html(str);
       foo('Loaded... 100%', function(str){$('div').html(str)});
 });


 function foo(str, callback) {

     for (i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
         $('div').append('. ');
     }

     //callback 
     if (typeof callback == "function") {
         callback(str);
     }
 }
```

The experience I want is for the user to see the 50% message first, until `foo()` is finished running the second time, when they would finally see the 100% message.

How can I run these functions synchronously to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: It does not need to by synchronous.  It's essentially a loader, I want 50% to show up before 100%, but I don't care which function runs first, or is completed first.

Answer (score 0):

Making the requests synchronous is not the best way to achieve what you need. In fact synchronous calls should be avoided where at all possible.

To achieve this you could store the requests in an array, and then update the progress based on the `state` of the deferred objects within that array. You can also use `$.when().then()` to execute logic after all requests complete. Try this:

```
var requests = [foo(), foo(), foo()]
$.when.apply($, requests).then(function() {
  $('div').after('All done!');
});

function foo(str) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: 'your-url-here.com',
    data: {
      foo: 'bar',
    },
    success: function(response) {
      var completed = requests.filter(function(r) { return r.state() == 'resolved'; })
      $('div').text(Math.round(completed.length / requests.length * 100, 0) + '% completed');
    }
  });
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/gf1mzt6e/)

Better still would be to amend the logic so you can send all the required information in a single request and then use the `progress` property to update the UI.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think I can use $.ajax.  I'm not calling an external file.  My loader is for a very large HTML page.

I have re-worded my question, here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43655982/how-to-create-a-progress-loader-for-a-very-large-html-file

Comment: In that case can you give a more concrete example of what your code is doing.